# How to Inject property file in Jenkins and use it values in Java Code

Tags: java, jenkins, property-files

I want to pass username and password in Jenkins by passing through property file and Use this credential in Java program to login to my app.

1. Inject property file in Jenkins
2. Use credentials from that file in my Java program to login to my app.

OR,
Other way around it, I can pass it as Password passing parameter for my jenkins job but I am not getting a way to fetch this password in my java program.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest way seems to be to pass it as a system property via the command line (-D option when you start the JVM)

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1)** prepare a java property file with username and password and put togerther with java code

```
username = xxx
password = xxx
```

**Step 2)** Config jenkins job to inject environment variable from property file

Option 1: check `Inject environment variables to the build process` under `Build Environment` section 
[image]

Option 2: Add a `Inject environment variable` build step and move it to the **top** on others build steps 
[image]

**For both options**, specify the credential property file path relative to jenkins job workspace

**Step 3)**  specify system property: username and password in java cmd line

for example:  `java -DUserName="${username}" -DPassWord="${password}"`

**Note**: 
1. `${xxx}`, the `xxx` from the key in property file, case sensitive. 
2. Please use double quote in case username or password includes space
3. The pattern `-Dxxx="${yyy}"` can work on both `Execute linux shell` and `Execute windows batch` build step.

[image]
[More about Java command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

**Step 4)**  obtain ssytem property: username and password in Java code

```
String userName = System.getProperty("UserName")
// the parameter: "UserName" from -Dxxxx, also case sensitive
```

[image]

[More about system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Comment: can you explain step#3 and 4 in more detail?

Comment: but in this way, I will have to pass default password in java code which could be access or view by others. which is not good in terms of security reason.

Comment: System.getProperty() has another version only accept one argument: system proterty name,  no default value required.

Comment: But this property file will be inside my Java project. Am I right? So In future if my credentials will get changed, I will have to access my java project & will need to change property file over there. Am I right?

Comment: If the username and password appear in job's console output is acceptable? If yes, i can update answer to generate auth file during job running(not exist source code). If no, you need to add credential file by Jenkins admin, then choose credential in job configuration.

Comment: the username and password appear in command line is acceptable for security requirement?

Comment: I think for security reason, what I am planning is to request admin to add credentials in jenkins and during job execution get that parameter in java class for login. I will have to see how to access the username and password passed as binding credentials in java